# Content of the block is outside of its limits (flex)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

It appears another area of the length pointed in flex option of .header__img class. What is the reseason of this situation and is it possible to make the content to be inside of the flex box?
HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__container _container">
        <a href="" class="header__logo">
            <div class="header__img"><img src="../static/goal.png" alt="Goal"></div>
            <div class="header__text">HireUs</div>
        </a>
        <nav class="header__menu menu">
            <ul class="menu__list">
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link menu__link-insurance">Health Insurance</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link menu__link-post">Post A Job</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link menu__link-login">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
.header {
    &__container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 140px;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    &__logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    &__img {
        flex: 0 0 50px;
        position: relative;
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    }

    &__text {
        color: $fontColor;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 900;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    }

    &__menu {
    }
}
```

How it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is pushing the text to the side. It is the `flex: 0 0 50px;` style of `header__img`, where you have set the basis of the image to be 50px. However, the flex container is only resized according to the size of the text. Apparently, this is because the image's container cannot grow while the image's position is set to absolute (and so it remains 0px wide), while the flexbox resizes according to the actual widths of its children (gaps and (I think some times) margins included).

I agree, it is weird. Flexboxes have always been weird to me, so I try to keep their usage simple.